# Regex matching only when condition has not been met

Tags: c#, regex

I have kind of a weird problem that I am attempting to resolve with some elegant regular expressions.

The system I am working on was initially designed to accept an incoming string and through a pattern matching method, alter the string which it then returns. A very simplistic example is:

Incoming string:

```
The dog & I went to the park and had a great time...
```

Outgoing string:

```
The dog {&} I went to the park and had a great time {...}
```

The punctuation mapper wraps key characters or phrases and wraps them in curly braces. The original implementation was a one way street and was never meant for how it is currently being applied and as a result, if it is called incorrectly, it is very easy for the system to "double" wrap a string as it is just doing a simple string replace.

I spun up Regex Hero this morning and started working on some pattern matches and having not written a regular expression in nearly a year, quickly hit a wall.

My first idea was to match a character (i.e. `&`) but only if it wasn't wrapped in braces and came up with `[^\{]&[^\}]`, which is great but of course catches any instance of the ampersand so long as it is not preceded by a curly brace, including white spaces and would not work in a situation where there were two ampersands back to back (i.e. `&&` would need to be `{&}{&}` in the outgoing string. To make matters more complicated, it is not always a single character as ellipsis (`...`) is also one of the mapped values.

Every solution I noodle over either hits a barrier because there is an unknown number of occurrences of a particular value in the string or that the capture groups will either be too greedy or finally, cannot compensate for multiple values back to back (i.e. a single period `.` vs ellipsis `...`) which the original dev handled by processing ellipsis first which covered the period in the string replace implementation.

Are there any regex gurus out there that have any ideas on how I can detect the undecorated (unwrapped) values in a string and then perform their replacements in an ungreedy fashion that can also handle multiple repeated characters?

My datasource that I am working against is a simple key value pair that contains the value to be searched for and the value to replace it with.

**Updated with example strings:**

Undecorated:

```
Show Details...   
Default Server:   
"Smart" 2-Way   
Show Lender's Information   
Black & White
```

Decorated:

```
Show Details{...}
Default Server{:}
{"}Smart{"} 2-Way
Show Lender{'}s Information
Black {&} White
```

**Updated With More Concrete Examples and Datasource**

Datasource (SQL table, can grow at any time):

- TaggedValue  UntaggedValue
- {:}  :
- {&}  &
- {<}  <
- {$}  $
- {'}  '
- {}  \
- {>}  >
- {"}  "
- {%}  %
- {...}    ...
- {...}    …
- {:}  ：
- {"}  “
- {"}  ”
- {'}  `
- {'}  ’

**Broken String:** `This is a string that already has stuff {&} other stuff{!} and {...} with {_} and {@} as well{.} and here are the same characters without it & follow by ! and ... _ & .  &&&`

**String that needs decoration:** `Show Details... Default Server: "Smart" 2-Way Show Lender's Information Black & White`

**String that would pass through the method untouched (because it was already decorated):** `The dog {&} I went to the park and had a great time {...}`

The other "gotcha" in moving to regex is the need to handle escaping, especially of backslashes elegantly due to their function in regular expressions.

**Updated with output from @Ethan Brown**

@Ethan Brown,

I am starting think that regex, while elegant might not be the way to go here. The updated code you provided, while closer still does not yield correct results and the number of variables involved may exceed the regex logics capability.

Using my example above:

`'This is a string that already has stuff {&} other stuff{!} and {...} with {_} and {@} as well{.} and here are the same characters without it & follow by ! and ... _ & . &&&'`

yields

`This is a string that already has stuff {&} other stuff{!} and {...} with {_} and {@} as well{.} and here are the same characters without it {&} follow by {!} and {...} {_} {&} . {&&}&`

Where the last group of ampersands which should come out as {&}{&}{&} actually comes out as {&&}&.

There is so much variability here (i.e. need to handle ellipsis and wide ellipsis from far east languages) and the need to utilize a database as the datasource is paramount.

I think I am just going to write a custom evaluator which I can easily enough write to perform this type of validation and shelve the regex route for now. I will grant you credit for your answer and work as soon as I get in front of a desktop browser.

Comment: Could you include a few sample strings?

Comment: Give some sample input and expected output!

Comment: In your example, the apostrophe in `Lender's` gets decorated, but the hyphen in `2-way` doesn't; why is that?  Aside from the faux ellipsis, are there any more multi-character sequences we need to accommodate, like `--` (faux m-dash)?  Will there ever be non-ASCII characters, like the real ellipsis (`…`) or m-dash (`—`)?

Comment: Sorry guys, had a death in the family today and had to run out of the office.

Essentially the datasource is static at this point and consists of 35 values and their decorations. At this point, ellipsis is the only multiple character value but it is not a guarantee that it will ever be the only one as the data comes from database and is updated separately from a web service push. 

As to why hypen is not decorated is because the system that this web service feeds does not handle hyphens in any special way and therefore it is not decorated (today.

Comment: Added with updated information and datasource.

Comment: Hi, JD: I explicitly stated in my solution that the input string would have to be padded (unless you want to add to the complexity of the regexp by alternating with `^` and `$` metacharacters).  My solution works on your input if you pad it.

Comment: That said, you could be right: there is a point at which a regex solution is more trouble than implementing something more robust.  Without knowing more about your problem, it would be hard to say if you were at that point or not.

Comment: @EthanBrown Even with the padding, the last 3 ampersands come out as {&&&} instead of three individual characters (i.e. {&}{&}{&}). I agree (and admittedly missed it in the original post) that {&&}& was the result of not padding it as necessary but the root problem of the grouping still exists. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, yes, right you are.  I left in the repetition operator (`+`) from my first solution.  I've updated my answer & it works as expected now.

Comment: @EthanBrown I think the best way I could describe the problem is one of normalization. Ellipsis is probably the best example. An ellipsis can come in many forms: three periods (...) or horizontal ellipsis (ASCII 133) and colon can be full width colon (U+FF1A) or regular every day colon (ASCII 58). There are certain characters that the app must both handle in special ways depending on the output as well as normalize them during import and "decorated" with curly braces for special handling later. The goal with regex was to identify the ones not decorated and process them on the fly.

Comment: Makes sense.  I think my updated regex will serve admirably for that problem.  You'll have to modify it accordingly for all of your characters, but I think it'll work just fine.

Comment: @EthanBrown I did run into one more "gotcha" that I am struggling with. The solution works well against undecorated "\\" (escaped backslashes). However, currently decorated escaped backslashes {\\} come out as {} because of the last part. I have been working at it for about an hour but this is outside my comfort zone of regex and nothing I am doing is making it better... but I can make it much worse :)

Comment: @EthanBrown - Update... I fixed it with '.RegexReplace("(?<=[^{])[\\\\](?=[^}])", "{$&}")'. Not sure if it is the best fix, but...

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it...those little edge cases are tough gotchas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem can be really tough, but let me give you some ideas that might help out.  One thing that's really going to give you headaches is handling the case where the punctuation appears at the beginning or end of the string.  Certainly that's possible to handle in a regex with a construct like `(^|[^{])&($|[^}])`, but in addition to that being painfully hard to read, it also has efficiency issues.  However, there's a simple way to "cheat" and get around this problem: just pad your input string with a space on either end:

```
var input = " " + originalInput + " ";
```

When you're done you can just trim.  Of course if you care about preserving input at the beginning or end, you'll have to be more clever, but I'm going to assume for argument's sake that you don't.

So now on to the meat of the problem.  Certainly, we can come up with some elaborate regular expressions to do what we're looking for, but often the answer is much much simpler if you use more than one regular expression.

Since you've updated your answer with more characters, and more problem inputs, I've updated this answer to be more flexible: hopefully it will meet your needs better as more characters get added.

Looking over your input space, and the expressions you need quoted, there are really three cases:

- Single-character replacements (! becomes {!}, for example).
- Multi-character replacements (... becomes {...}).
- Slash replacement (\ becomes {})

Since the period is included in the single-character replacements, order matters: if you replace all the periods first, then you will miss ellipses.

Because I find the C# regex library a little clunky, I use the following extension method to make this more "fluent":

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string RegexReplace( this string s, string regex, string replacement ) {
        return Regex.Replace( s, regex, replacement );
    }
}
```

Now I can cover all of the cases:

```
// putting this into a const will make it easier to add new
// characters in the future
const string normalQuotedChars = @"\!_\\:&<\$'>""%:`";

var output = s
    .RegexReplace( "(?<=[^{])\\.\\.\\.(?=[^}])", "{$&}" )
    .RegexReplace( "(?<=[^{])[" + normalQuotedChars + "](?=[^}])", "{$&}" )
    .RegexReplace( "\\\\", "{}" );
```

So let's break this solution down:

1. First we handle the ellipses (which will keep us from getting in trouble with periods later).  Note that we use a [zero-width assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion) at the beginning and end of the expression to *exclude* expressions that are already quoted.  The zero-width assertions are necessary, because without them, we'd get into trouble with quoted characters right next to each other.  For example, if you have the regex `([^{])!([^}])`, and your input string is `foo !! bar`, the match would include the space before the first exclamation point and the *second exclamation point*.  A naive replacement of `$1!$2` would therefore yield `foo {!}! bar` because the second exclamation point would have been consumed as part of the match.  You'd have to end up doing an exhaustive match, and it's much easier to just use zero-width assertions, which are not consumed.
2. Then we handle all of the normal quoted characters.  Note that we use zero-width assertions here for the same reasons as above.
3. Finally, we can find lone slashes (note we have to escape it twice: once for C# strings and again for regex metacharacters) and replace that with empty curly brackets.

I ran all of your test cases (and a few of my own invention) through this series of matches, and it all worked as expected.

Comment: Ethan,

Thanks for the through reply. We had a death in the family today and I will likely not get back to this code (or work) for a few days. I will read this over and reply asap. 

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your loss, JD.

Comment: Ethan,

I am updating my initial question with some more concrete examples as well as my datasource for tagged and untagged values. Some are unicode (wide period, etc...) characters. On the most simplistic examples (strings that are either fully decorated or fully undecorated), it works. However as soon as I send in a "broken" string that is partially decorated, it starts to fall apart.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  I'll take a look at it today.

Comment: Updated my initial post with results. Thanks again for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex god, so one simple way:

- Get / construct the final replacement string(s) - ex. "{...}", "{&}"
- Replace all occurrences of these in the input with a reserved char (unicode to the rescue)
- Run your matching regex(es) and put "{" or whatever desired marker(s).
- Replace reserved char(s) with the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the case where your original input string has a `{` or `}` character, a common way to avoid re-applying a regex to an already-escaped string is to look for the escape sequence and remove it from the string before applying your regex to the remainders. Here's an example regex to find things that are already escaped:

```
Regex escapedPattern = new Regex(@"\{[^{}]*\}"); // consider adding RegexOptions.Compiled
```

The basic idea of this negative-character class pattern comes from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), a very helpful site for all thing regex. The pattern works because for any inner-most pair of braces, there must be a `{` followed by non `{}`'s followed by a `}`

Run the `escapedPattern` on the input string, find for each `Match` get the start and end indices in the original string and substring them out, then with the final cleaned string run your original pattern match again or use something like the following:

```
Regex punctPattern = new Regex(@"[^\w\d\s]+"); // this assumes all non-word, 
      // digit or space chars are punctuation, which may not be a correct 
      //assumption
```

And replace `Match.Groups[1].Value` for each match (groups are a 0 based array where 0 is the whole match, 1 is the first set of parentheses, 2 is the next etc.) with `"{" + Match.Groups[1].Value + "}"`

Comment: Alan,

Thanks for the through reply. We had a death in the family today and I will likely not get back to this code (or work) for a few days. I will read this over and reply asap. 

Thanks again.